# C# and partially working SendMessage?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I've tried to send text messages to various applications in Windows 7 (eg. Notepad++, Notepad etc.). SendMessage is working fine for Notepad but not for Notepad++.

If i'm sending text to Notepad everything appears fine, whole text and i'm getting 1 as return from SendMessage method. But for Notepad++ only first letter appears and method SendMessage is returning 0, however Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() is not returning any error (result 0)?

Here's the code:

```
GUITHREADINFO gti = new GUITHREADINFO();
IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
uint processId;
uint activeThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processId);
if (GetInfo(activeThreadId, out gti))
{
    int EM_REPLACESEL = 0x00C2;

    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    int result = SendMessageW(gti.hwndCaret, EM_REPLACESEL, -1, passed);//3rd param doesn't change anything
    error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
}
```

WinAPI functions and GetInfo method as long with required structures are defined as:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageW", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
//"Borrowed" code
public static bool GetInfo(uint hwnd, out GUITHREADINFO lpgui)
{
     uint lpdwProcessId;
     uint threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out lpdwProcessId);

     lpgui = new GUITHREADINFO();
     lpgui.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(lpgui);

    return GetGUIThreadInfo(threadId, ref lpgui);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int iLeft;
    public int iTop;
    public int iRight;
    public int iBottom;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct GUITHREADINFO
{
    public int cbSize;
    public int flags;
    public IntPtr hwndActive;
    public IntPtr hwndFocus;
    public IntPtr hwndCapture;
    public IntPtr hwndMenuOwner;
    public IntPtr hwndMoveSize;
    public IntPtr hwndCaret;
    public RECT rectCaret;
}
```

So well i wonder what should i do to fix it so it would work (fully) for all windows not only for edit control in Notepad?

Comment: EM_REPLACESEL should only be sent to an Edit or RichEdit control.  That's not what Notepad++ uses.

Comment: `GetLastWin32Error` won't return anything useful after calling `SendMessage`. You should ONLY EVER call that function if the previous call returns a value that says you should. In all other cases, the value is undefined.